# How do we how to embed JavaFX in html WITHOUT an applet?

Tags: html, javafx

I have code written in JavaFX but am trying to embed it into an Bootstrap .html file without an applet.

Comment: That's not possible. Java runs in a JVM. The only way to run Java inside a browser is via an applet, but that too is now obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

As sillyfly has already said in his comment, this is not possible with standard Java. But there is a new technology which can make that possible.

https://www.jpro.io/

Maybe you can apply for their currently still closed beta program.